# Identity Server 4 Protect an API

Tags: c#, api, identityserver4

I'm trying to use Identity Server 4 to protect my API. Now I have gone through all the documentation at http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html and I have set up a few successful demos. However, there is one thing that I am failing to understand.

For example, First, we need to define a client on the IS4 that looks like this:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "client",

    // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

    // secret for authentication
    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },

    // scopes that client has access to
    AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
}
```

Then on the API we protect it by adding the `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` package and adding configuration to startup.cs

```
services.AddMvcCore()
    .AddAuthorization()
    .AddJsonFormatters();

services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ApiName = "api1";
    });
```

And then finally we add `app.UseAuthentication();`

Now, this all works when ran, however, the part that I don't understand is where is the secret defined in the API. As you can see, the client clearly expects a secret and yet I don't define this secret anywhere on my API. I also don't define anywhere on the IS4 anything about my API to say that you are protecting the API from this URI or something along those lines.

So how does this actually works in terms of IS4 knowing about the API and authenticating its requests?

EDIT:

To clarify some confusion, yes there is a client that I opted out in code above and I see now that I shouldn't, and in there I provide a secret, but I'm still not understanding how does the IS4 knows to protect my specific API. What if the request came from www.somerandomapi.com? From what I"m reading it would work regardless. Based on what you wrote, it does make sense that the client is passing the secret, but nowhere in my code is the IS4 told which API to protect.

Comment: The secret is passed in from the client (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html#creating-the-client)

Comment: I'm extremely sure this doesn't work. How do you, exactly, know that it works?

Comment: @DavidG The question is why "it works" when the client isn't passing the credentials. I'm sure it doesn't work, though

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The client *is* passing in the secret though, that's how it get the bearer access token. The code works fine.

Comment: @DavidG Huh, I only see the secret defined in the IDS side, not in the API

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto `var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "client", "secret");`

Comment: @DavidG I know that, but that's not part of the question's code :)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto But that's how it works! The code above doesn't show the flow, just the setup. The question "where is the secret defined in the API" is meaningless - it's not defined there at all.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, but then it means this is not a MCVE. You can do it completely in configuration without using the TokenClient

Comment: Please see my edit. I tried to clarify some confusion here.

Comment: @KirkLarkin so that means anyone can use my IS4?

Comment: No, not at all. Can you explain in more detail what clients you have, etc?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Outside of the one I posted above, just an MVC client which is HybridAndClientCredentials

Comment: The API doesn't need a secret at all, as has been said. However, any *client* that wants to consume your API either needs a secret or a *preregistered* redirect url, for example, in order to get a valid token that your API will accept. `www.somerandomapi.com` cannot get a token unless it has a client-secret (which it doesn't) *or* it's registered using the implicit flow and has registered a known redirect url with your IS4 instance (which, again, it hasn't).

Comment: @KirkLarkin Ah so RedirectUris acts as my whitelist of which website can use the IS4 then if a secret is not provided.

Comment: Yup, that's right. You can't have secrets in e.g. an Angular application so you use a whitelisted redirect URL for that instead.

Comment: @KirkLarkin yes that was what worried me as I would like to connect an angular application and putting a secret in there is like not putting one up at all, maybe just a bit of obscurity but not security. Thanks for the epxlanation, maybe you can turn it into an aswer I can mark correct?

Comment: @Bojan - just some clarification. IS4 in general doesn't know to protect your API. IS4 is issuing tokens (which can have your api name as a scope in them, if requested and allowed of course). Your API is validating these tokens, against IS4 (` options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";` is the clue here). So if `www.somerandomapi.com` is a valid IS4 client, and is allowed access to your API scope, then it will receive a valid token from IS4 and will be able to access your API. But for `www.somerandomapi.com` to be a valid client, it should be registered in your IS4.